# Delay specific transform property CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to make it so that the `rotate(-45deg)` property gets delayed a shortly after the first property `translateY(6px)` with the help of a delay. But how do I do that?

Code:

```
transform: translateY(6px) rotate(-45deg);
```

I first thought it was something like:
`transform: translateY(6px) rotate(-45deg, 2s);`

Comment: You can't delay one of the `transform`'s values using `transition`. With `animation` it is possible though...as suggested in one answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the transformation using two different properties. You keep the rotation within transform and you use top/bottom to add the translation.

```css
.box {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or you can consider `animation`:

```css
.box {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
}

.box:hover {
  animation:change 1s linear forwards
}

@keyframes change {
  50% {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```